# Update order meta with cart item custom data in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, woocommerce

On a woocommerce single page product, I have created a custom field. And i want its value to be stored in the order meta, when the order is validated. After several hours of research i have not been able to find any solution to come to the end ! But i'm sure i'm pretty close to it...

Here is my actual code:

```
 // create the custom field
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_fields_before_add_to_cart', 100 );
  function add_fields_before_add_to_cart($post) {
    ?>
    <select class="selectpicker" name="premiere_box_abo" id="premiere_box_abo">
      <option value="Septembre 2018">Septembre 2018</option>
      <option value="Octobre 2018">Octobre 2018</option>        
    </select>
    <?php
  }

  // Store custom field
  function save_my_custom_checkout_field( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['premiere_box_abo'] ) ) {
      $cart_item_data[ 'premiere_box_abo' ] = $_POST['premiere_box_abo'];
      /* below statement make sure every add to cart action as unique line item */
      $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
  }
  add_action( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_my_custom_checkout_field', 10, 2 );

  // Render meta on cart and checkout
  function render_meta_on_cart_and_checkout( $cart_data, $cart_item = null ) {
    $custom_items = array();
    /* Woo 2.4.2 updates */
    if( !empty( $cart_data ) ) {
      $custom_items = $cart_data;
    }
    if( isset( $cart_item['premiere_box_abo'] ) ) {
      $custom_items[] = array( "name" => '1e box abonnement', "value" => $cart_item['premiere_box_abo'] );
    }
    return $custom_items;
  }
  add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'render_meta_on_cart_and_checkout', 10, 2 );

  // Display as order meta
  add_action( 'woocommerce_add_order_item_meta', 'my_field_order_meta_handler', 1, 3 );
  function my_field_order_meta_handler( $item_id, $values ) {
    if( isset( $values['premiere_box_abo'] ) ) {
      wc_add_order_item_meta( $item_id, "1e box abonnement", $values['premiere_box_abo'] );
    }
  }

 // Update the order meta with field value
 add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
   function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
      if ( ! empty( $_POST['premiere_box_abo'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'premiere_box_abo', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['premiere_box_abo'] ) );
   }
  }
```

And here is **What I have so far:**

[image: what I have so far]

That is what I would like :

[image: what I would like]

How can I save this custom field data as order meta data to make appear the value in "custom fields" meta box.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since woocommerce 3, you code is a bit outdated and has small mistakes.

> Also to answer your main question, you are trying to save some "item" data as order meta data, which is not the best thing to do as you can have many items for an order.

I have revisited your code below:

```
// Display a custom select field below add to cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_field_before_add_to_cart', 10 );
function add_field_before_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;
    ?>
    <select class="selectpicker" name="premiere_box_abo" id="premiere_box_abo">
        <option value="Septembre 2018">Septembre 2018</option>
        <option value="Septembre 2018">Octobre 2018</option>
    </select>
    <?php
}

// Add select field value as custom cart item data
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_cart_item_custom_data', 20, 2 );
function add_cart_item_custom_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['premiere_box_abo'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['custom_data'] = esc_attr($_POST['premiere_box_abo']);
        $cart_item_data['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Display custom cart item data in cart and checkout
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'display_custom_cart_item_data', 20, 2 );
function display_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $cart_item ) {
    if( isset( $cart_item['custom_data'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data[] = array(
            'name' => __('1e box abonnement'),
            'value' => $cart_item['custom_data']
        );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

// Save / Display custom field value as custom order item meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'custom_field_update_order_item_meta', 20, 4 );
function custom_field_update_order_item_meta( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if( isset($values['custom_data']) ){
        $item->update_meta_data( __('1e box abonnement'), $values['custom_data'] );
    }
}

// Save custom fields values as custom order meta data
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta', 20, 2 );
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order, $data ) {
    $premiere_box_abo = array();

    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
        // Set each order item '1e box abonnement' in an array
        $premiere_box_abo[] = $item->get_meta( __('1e box abonnement') );
    }
    // Save the data as a coma separated string in order meta data
    if( sizeof($premiere_box_abo) > 0 )
        $order->update_meta_data( 'premiere_box_abo', implode( ',', $premiere_box_abo ) );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.