# Add cart metadata to admin order screen in Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a hidden input that I'm populating with some JS on a Woocommerce product screen that I'm trying to access the information on the order metadata that gets sent to the admin screen and admin order notification, but I cannot get access to.

I feel like I can append information to a cart item, but that doesn't come through the final order.

#### Adding hidden field

```php
function add_polarity_custom_hidden_field() {
    global $product;
    ob_start(); //Side note...not sure I need Output buffering here, feel free to let me know.
    
//Here's the input (value is populated with a separate radio group using JS)
?>

<input type="hidden" id="polarity-info" name="polarity_information" value=""> 

<?php
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_flush();
    return $content;
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_variations_table', 'add_polarity_custom_hidden_field', 10);
```

Which I'm using this function below to add the value of the hidden input to the cart item (Not trying to display this information to the customer)

#### Adding the custom data to the cart line item:

```php
/**
 * Add custom data to Cart
 */
function add_polarity_info_to_order($cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id) {
    if (isset($_REQUEST['polarity_information'])) {
        $cart_item_data['polarity_information'] = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['polarity_information']);
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_polarity_info_to_order', 10, 3);
```

#### Displaying on the admin page as order metadata:

I'm trying to get that information to display on the

1. Order Notification Email as item Metadata
2. Admin line items, also as item Metadata

I tried using this function like so, but cannot access the properties I'm looking for:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', function ($order) {
    $order->get_ID();
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item) {
        $allmeta = $item->get_meta_data();
        var_dump($allmeta); //Not within these properties.
    }
});
```

---

### Side Note

I can get the items to display on the cart page using the below code, but I cannot get this to translate to the final order.

```php
/**
 * Display information as Meta on Cart page
 */
function add_polarity_data_to_cart_page($item_data, $cart_item) {



    if (array_key_exists('polarity_information', $cart_item)) {
        $polarity_details = $cart_item['polarity_information'];

        $item_data[] = array(
            'key'   => 'Polarity Information',
            'value' => $polarity_details
        );
    }

    return $item_data;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', 'add_polarity_data_to_cart_page', 10, 2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use the [`woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item`](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-checkout.html#source-view.489) hook to store the cart data as the order item meta data.

So:

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_custom_order_item_meta_data', 10, 4 );
function save_custom_order_item_meta_data( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {

    if ( isset( $values['polarity_information'] ) ) {
        $item->update_meta_data( '_polarity_information', $values['polarity_information'] );
    }

}
```

You can now access the order item meta data from the `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details` hook.

*The code has been tested and worked. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*

**RELATED ANSWERS**

- [Save Woocommerce cart item custom data as order item meta data displaying it on orders and emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65783099/save-woocommerce-cart-item-custom-data-as-order-item-meta-data-displaying-it-on)
- [How to get cart item key from order item in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58171738/how-to-get-cart-item-key-from-order-item-in-woocommerce)
- [Add and display custom cart item data in WooCommerce orders and emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65694153/add-and-display-custom-cart-item-data-in-woocommerce-orders-and-emails)
- [Update order meta with cart item custom data in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51698790/update-order-meta-with-cart-item-custom-data-in-woocommerce-3)

Comment: Thank you! This has solved the issue, one last question - the order meta is coming in as "_polarity_information". Can I safely change that in your function to a more human-readable string like "Polarity Information", or do I need to alter it in the function another way?

Comment: Using capitalization and/or spaces in the meta key could cause unexpected behavior. As with other meta, the name chosen for the meta key should be all lowercase with no spaces (to be replaced with underscores). **This way you will surely have no problems.** Since it's a custom meta you will be managing it and you can label this meta key from the code. However, feel free to experiment.

Comment: Awesome, thanks again, Vincenzo!